# Live Kali Linux через USB устанавливается больше дня

Tags: linux, usb, kali-linux, asus

[Делал всё по этой ссылке](https://devanswers.co/guide-kali-linux-2018-live-usb-persistence-windows/), нам её в универе дали. В итоге у меня после бута линукса, началось вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ноутбук Asus, куплен 3 месяца назад, тобишь железо отличное. Я думал, что эта "инсталяция" или что это, займёт порядка 1-ну максимум 3 часов. В итоге после 12 часов (на ночь оставил), понял что пора искать проблему.

Comment: Используй кали только в лайф режиме. А эта железяка не очень подходит линуксу.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не о программировании.

Answer (score 6):

Это kernel panic. Если Вы не знаете что это такое, наверное, не стоит использовать kali linux, т.к. он нацелен на опытных пользователей, занимающихся IT безопасностью. Да и вообще, использование kali linux крайне неоправданно, т.к. все утилиты из его состава можно найти в обычном дистре, который при этом установится и не будет вызывать проблем.

Comment: *не стоит использовать kali linux, т.к. он нацелен на опытных пользователей, занимающихся IT безопасностью* - золотые слова! +1

Comment: Сейчас просто тренд :)