# Проблема с установкой Kali Linux

Tags: linux, windows-10, dual-boot, kali-linux, uefi

Недавно попытался установить Kali Linux. Вроде бы все делал по инструкции: выделил специальное место для Kali Linux (я хотел, чтобы эта ОС была рядом с Windows 10), записал образ на флешку.
Далее Запустил UEFI, выбрал саму флешку и началась загрузка. Выделил место для диска и файла подкачки. Вроде бы все прошло успешно. Перезагрузил ноутбук и запускаю Kali Linux. Что-то там понаписывало и в конце просто был _
Ждал я минут 10, но было безрезультатно. Тогда я вырубил ноутбук и попробовал снова. Сначала все было как всегда(включая _). Но когда я подождал примерно секунд 10, то появился курсор мыши, а немного позже и сам интерфейс. Ввел логин и пароль, а потом весь интерфейс пропал, кроме пустого серого фона. Также ждал достаточно, но ничего не помогло.
Что мне делать, чтобы убрать данную проблему?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Live Kali Linux через USB устанавливается больше дня](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/932760/live-kali-linux-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-usb-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8f)

Comment: так проблема еще кроется в том, что я попытался убунту установить, но тоже был буроватый экран и все. без интерфейса

Comment: Ну вы же об этом не писали. Разделы как делали? Kali плохой выбор, если у вас опыта работы с ОС на ядре linux нет. Это как не умея управлять автомобилем сразу сесть за руль спорткара

Comment: выбрал автоматически и мне выделил тот диск

Comment: да. Был просто цвет багроватого/буроватого экрана. Без интерфейса

Comment: Я немного попользовался убунту на VB. Потому решил поставить хотя бы какой-нибудь дистрибутив linux. Кали я уже понял, что был неудачный выбор. Но с убунту тоже дела были не очень. Даже сегодня пытался Mint установить, но была просто загрузка. Потом все остановилось(точки остановились) и все. Ждал я где-то минут 5, но все было также. Вообщем проблемы за проблемой)

Comment: [Как запустить Ubuntu c загрузочного диска на USB / Как вернуться в Windows?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/866765/262779) - может пригодится

Comment: В случае ссылки там Windows стоит приоритетной ОС, можете зайдя в BIOS изменить на Linux, тогда будет грузится сначала GRUB с вариантами загрузки